# Mapping a firebase documentsnapshot to a custom model that requires key and values and provide it as a stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to provide a stream of document snapshot to a widget but before that, I want to map the snapshot which returns a Map<String, dynamic> to a custom model such that the model takes the key and value of each field and passes it to the model then creates a list of all the UserInfo object based on the several fields in the snapshot document

```
class DatabaseService {
  final CollectionReference userCollection =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  // the map function

  List<UserInfo> _userInfo(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    //the line below is where i get the error that the expression has a type 'void' and it can't be used
    snapshot.data().forEach((key, value) {
      return UserInfo(key: key, value: value);
    }).toList();
  }

// The stream

Stream<List<UserInfo>> get userData {
  return userCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userInfo);
}
```

Here is the model UserInfo

```
class UserInfo {
  final String key;
  final dynamic value;

  UserInfo({this.key, this.value});
}
```

I would very much appreciate any help I can get here.

I am also very much aware that I can pass a stream to a widget using a stream builder but I'm trying to get to use this method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `map` to transform the iterable (list) into something. `forEach` can't be used for that as it can't return anything.

```dart
List<UserInfo> _userInfo(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    final data = snapshot.data();
    return data.keys().map((key) {
      return UserInfo(key: key, value: data[key]);
    }).toList();
}
```

Comment: I just tried that, it gave 2 errors: 'UserInfo' isn't a 'MapEntry<_, _>, as required by the closure's context. The second is: .toList() isn't defined for the type 'Map'.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you wish you can accept/upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your model

```
class UserInfo {
      final String key;
      final dynamic value;
    
      UserInfo({this.key, this.value});
    
      UserInfo.mapping(String k, String v) : 
                      key = k,
                      value = v;
}
```

And after that you can have Tirth Patel's answer with little bit of a tweak:

```
List<UserInfo> _userInfo(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data().map((key, value) {
      return UserInfo.mapping(key, value);
    }).toList();
}
```

Be aware of the type of the variables for ***k*** and ***v*** and also for ***key*** and ***value***

I was not really able to test it but I think it will work.